# Drawing the blue "unread dot" on the iPhone Mail app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, quartz-graphics

Does anyone have an example of how to draw the blue "unread dot" used in Apple's Mail App? This one in specific:

[image]

Drawing an ellipse is straight forward with Quartz2d, but the subtle use of shadows+gradients make this look really 3d.

Answer (score 9):

I think the blue dot in mail is actually an image; I would imagine that blitting an image would be faster than drawing a gradient.

Comment: Yes, you could probably find the image in MobileMail.app's resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to go with a resource there is an app called UIKit-Artwork-Extractor that allows you to rip all the resources from all the IOS apps you have installed

https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor