# Blue mail dot in SDK?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, uitableview

Is the little blue mail dot the iPhone mail program uses to signify new mail, on each tableview cell, available in the SDK?  Or, it is available for download some where on the Internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am quite sure you might have to download it (an image file), or find the image in the SDK. I haven't heard of any command/link to add the blue mail dot in an iPhone application.  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875035/drawing-the-blue-unread-dot-on-the-iphone-mail-app)
is very similar to the one you are asking *and* includes the blue mail dot picture

Comment: Cool, thanks.  Unless someone else chimes in with something different, I believe that will work.